# Get the max value one column but group on another

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I am trying to figure out how to get an entire row for the latest record of a user. I have a table where it's basically a log of all users who do an action and a date time. So for example

| userId | action | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jump | 2022-01-01 07:50:00.000 |
| 2 | run | 2022-01-02 07:50:00.000 |
| 3 | walk | 2022-01-01 07:50:00.000 |
| 3 | run | 2022-01-04 07:50:00.000 |
| 4 | jump | 2022-01-01 07:50:00.000 |
| 2 | walk | 2022-01-01 07:50:00.000 |
| 1 | walk | 2022-01-01 01:50:00.000 |
| 1 | walk | 2022-01-03 04:50:00.000 |
| 4 | run | 2022-01-03 07:50:00.000 |

Basically I would want to query this table in order to return just the latest datetime rows for each unique user like this:

| userId | action | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | walk | 2022-01-03 04:50:00.000 |
| 2 | run | 2022-01-02 07:50:00.000 |
| 3 | run | 2022-01-04 07:50:00.000 |
| 4 | run | 2022-01-03 07:50:00.000 |

So far I tried doing this

```
select u.userid, u.action, u.datetime
from user_logs u
inner join (
    select userid, max(datetime) as datetime 
    from user_logs
    group by userid
) tmp on tmp.userid = u.userid and tmp.datetime = u.datetime
order by u.userid
```

However this seems to still give me multiple rows with duplicate userids, different action statuses, but with all the same datetime now

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to the rescue.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (userId INT, action  VARCHAR(10), actionTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl (userId, action, actionTime) VALUES
(1, 'jump', '2022-01-01 07:50:00.000'),
(2, 'run' , '2022-01-02 07:50:00.000'),
(3, 'walk', '2022-01-01 07:50:00.000'),
(3, 'run' , '2022-01-04 07:50:00.000'),
(4, 'jump', '2022-01-01 07:50:00.000'),
(2, 'walk', '2022-01-01 07:50:00.000'),
(1, 'walk', '2022-01-01 01:50:00.000'),
(1, 'walk', '2022-01-03 04:50:00.000'),
(4, 'run' , '2022-01-03 07:50:00.000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY actionTime DESC) AS seq
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
| userId | action |       actionTime        | seq |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
|      1 | walk   | 2022-01-03 04:50:00.000 |   1 |
|      2 | run    | 2022-01-02 07:50:00.000 |   1 |
|      3 | run    | 2022-01-04 07:50:00.000 |   1 |
|      4 | run    | 2022-01-03 07:50:00.000 |   1 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical case for [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/).

```
select userid, action, datetime
  from (select u.*,
               row_number() over (partition by userid order by datetime desc) rn
          from user_logs u) _
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the latest row for each user.

For example, you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by userId order by datetime desc) as rn
  from user_logs
) x
where rn = 1
```